# Как распарсить данный код?

Tags: php

Добрый вечер.
Помогите пожалуйста разобраться в данном коде, не могу понять, как его распарсить на php?
сам код:

```
Array ( 
[0] => a:2:{i:0;a:4:{s:5:"index";s:1:"0";s:4:"name";s:10:"blackcolor";s:6:"amount";s:5:"25.00";s:8:"shipping";s:1:"1";}i:1;a:4:{s:5:"index";s:1:"1";s:4:"name";s:10:"browncolor";s:6:"amount";s:5:"25.00";s:8:"shipping";s:1:"1";}}
[1] => a:1:{i:0;a:4:{s:5:"index";s:1:"0";s:4:"name";s:2:"48";s:6:"amount";s:5:"48.00";s:8:"shipping";s:1:"1";}}
[2] => a:1:{i:0;a:4:{s:5:"index";s:1:"0";s:4:"name";s:2:"47";s:6:"amount";s:5:"48.00";s:8:"shipping";s:1:"1";}}
[3] => a:1:{i:0;a:4:{s:5:"index";s:1:"0";s:4:"name";s:2:"47";s:6:"amount";s:5:"48.00";s:8:"shipping";s:1:"1";}}
[4] => a:1:{i:0;a:4:{s:5:"index";s:1:"0";s:4:"name";s:0:"";s:6:"amount";s:5:"35.00";s:8:"shipping";s:1:"1";}}
[5] => a:1:{i:0;a:3:{s:4:"name";s:10:"ismarprice";s:6:"amount";s:4:"5.00";s:8:"shipping";s:1:"1";}}
[6] => a:1:{i:1;a:3:{s:5:"index";s:1:"1";s:4:"name";s:3:"qwe";s:6:"amount";s:6:"123.00";}} 
)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это сериализованные объекты/массивы

http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php